# Use the Hahn-Banach theorem to show that if every bounded linear map $T:X_{1} \rightarrow X_{2}$ is surjective, then $\dim X_{2}=1$.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces

I found the following question in my textbook:

Let $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ normed spaces (both nontrivial). Use the Hahn-Banach theorem to show that if every bounded linear map $T:X_{1} \rightarrow X_{2}$ is surjective, where $T \neq 0$, then $\dim X_{2}=1$.

---

At the time I had few ideas, but i can't solve it. If someone help me, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Take two independent vectors and functionals that kill them in turn.

Comment: Maybe you didn't state the problem quite correctly? In fact if every bounded linear map is surjective then $X_2=\{0\}$. Obviously; the map $Tx=0$ is bounded and linear. Now since we're also given that $X_2$ is non-trivial it follows that there is no such $X_2$ at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $e$ a  non zero vector of $X_2$ and $f$ a non zero vector of $X_1$, the map $h:Vect(f)\rightarrow Vect(e)$ defined by $h(f)=e$ is bounded it can be extended to $X_1$ by Hahn Banach so it is surjective by hypothesis and $X_2=Vect(e)$.

Comment: Can you extend $h$? Remember that Hahn-Banach extesion is for $f :X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Do you see really a big difference between a linear map which takes its value in a 1-dimensional vector space and a linear form?

Answer (score 3):

Hahn-Banach implies that for every $z\in X_1$ there exists a continuous linear functional $\varphi$ from $X_1$ to the scalars, having norm 1 and mapping $z$ to its own norm.

Pick any nonzero $z\in X_1$ and nonzero $y\in X_2$. Then $x\mapsto \varphi(x)y$ is a continuous linear mapping that only hits the multiples of $y.$ It cannot be surjective unless $X_2$ is generated by $y.$